# Laravel 4- Duplication/Unique fires on data update how to prevent

Tags: php, validation, model, laravel, laravel-4

I have table named keywords as below

```
id  keyword syntax  description
```

I have a form that is used  to edit KEYWORD details, i have the same validation rules on this form as i do on the create form as well as the database.

Basically the **keyword** has to be unique, but when updating if i just want to update the **keywords details**  then it will fail and warn me that **keyword** already exists, so i cannot update the **keyowords** as their **keyword** has not been changed and thus throwing the database unique rule at me.

MY model class

```
public static $rules = array(

                                'keyword' => 'required|unique:keywords',
                                'syntax'=>'required',
                                'description'=>'required'
                                );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force the validator to ignore `unique` rule for a given `id` you may pass the `id` of that recored which is being validated, for example:

```
'keyword' => 'required|unique:keywords,keyword,10'
```

This, will not check uniqueness of the model if the `id` is `10`, so when you are updating the model you need to pass the `id` of the current model to ignore the unique rule on this model:

```
'keyword' => 'required|unique:keywords,keyword,' . $id
```

Since your rules variable is `public static $rules` so you may access it from the controller and in this case before you run the validation in update method you need to change the rules for your `keywords` field and I think you can change the rule like this (just set new rules for that field):

```
// Replace the Model with the name of your model within the controller
// update method before the validation takes place
Model::$rules['keyword'] = 'required|unique:keywords,keyword,' . $id;
```

Check the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique).

Comment: Can you kindly look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39591620/how-to-prevent-insert-email-if-already-exist-with-specific-id-in-laravel/. Actually need guideline

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in separate ways.

**#1**
An easy way is to use [Ardent](https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent) which takes care of this part .
**#2**
When you edit, 
You can pass to Validator, a 'ignore id rule'

```
$rules = array(

                                'keyword' => 'required|unique:keywords,'.$id,
                                'syntax'=>'required',
                                'description'=>'required'
                                );
```

**#3**
A more complicated way is to use Validation as a service. Different rules based on different actions . When you will create the model, you will use the rules that you currently have.

When you will update the model, you will change the unique:keywords to exists:keywords

I usually do this with a validation service.

You create a base abstract Validator in services/ , which has a passes() function.

For each model, you create a ModelValidator , in your case CityValidator. Where you put your rules like :

```
public static $rules = array(
                           'new'=>[

                                'keyword' => 'required|unique:keyword',
                                'syntax'=>'required',
                                'description'=>'required'],
                           'edit'=>[
                                'keyword' => 'required|exists:keyword',
                                'syntax'=>'required',
                                'description'=>'required'
                                 ]
                                )
```

Answer (score 1):

## define Rules

class Dev extends \Eloquent

```
public static $rules = array(
    'id' => "required|min:1|max:999|unique:dev,id",
    'name' => 'required|min:2|max:32|unique:dev,name',
    'alias' => 'required|min:2|max:32|unique:dev,alias',
);
```

## apply Rules

class TreeController extends \BaseController {

```
public function update($id)
{
    $rules = Dev::$rules;
    if ($id !== null) {
        $rules['id'] .= ",$id";
        $rules['name'] .= ",$id";
        $rules['alias'] .= ",$id";
    }

    $input = array_except(Input::all(), '_method');
    $v = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($v->passes()) {
        $dev = $this->dev->find($id);
        try {
            $dev->update($input);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Session::flash('error', $e->getMessage());
        }
        return Redirect::route('adm.pattern.dev.index');
    } else {
        Session::flash('error', implode('<br />', $v->errors()->all(':message')));
        return Redirect::route('adm.pattern.dev.edit', $id)->withInput()->withErrors($v);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Just a suggestion. You should probably add some explanation with the code. Just so the answer is clearer.