# How to update unique field in Laravel collective?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravelcollective

I have a user admin panel where admin can create update users and while users have a unique email field. While updating when I don't wanna change the email address it should be as it is. but throwing me error   like:  `The email has already been taken.`

I already tried:

1. [How to prevent insert email if already exist with specific id in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39591620/how-to-prevent-insert-email-if-already-exist-with-specific-id-in-laravel)
2. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique

and my user model rule

```
'email' => 'required|unique:users,email,{$user->id}'
```

what I'm missing here? **please help**

Comment: I don't feel updating email address of a user is a good idea. This way, you would never have that field in a form.

Comment: Probably provide more context on why you want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user only changes the name field and not the e-mail field, you do not want a validation error to be thrown because the user is already the owner of the e-mail address.

you can use like:

```
'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
],
```

Read Under the Section **Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID:** [LINK](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-email)